# How can I change a CSS parameter that comes from a 'class' property?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to modify some CSS properties in a given element, this way:

```
var rsc_menu = document.getElementById("rsc_menu");
rsc_menu.style.top = 303;
rsc_menu.style.height = 29;
```

Unfortunately, after code execution the element still stays in its original position and preserves its original size.
I've noticed that `alert(rsc_menu.style.top)` and `alert(rsc_menu.style.height)` both show an empty box.
The element is declared like this:

```
<div class="resources_menu" id="rsc_menu">
```

As you can see, it takes all of its styling parameters from a foreign stylesheet; I defined no `style` tags for it. May that be the problem? Is there any way to accomplish the task without having to change the `<div>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass it:

1. As a string
2. With a valid unit

So your code would be looking like this:

```
var rsc_menu = document.getElementById("rsc_menu");
rsc_menu.style.top = "303px";
rsc_menu.style.height = "29px";
```